# How to obtain pdf byte[] from PdfDocument using itext7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm having difficulty understanding how to obtain the content from a PdfDocument. I've learned from previous questions that PdfDocument flushes the content to optimize working with large documents. If my function returns a new PdfDocument, how do I get the byte[] to pass into my other functions?

Even with PdfDocument.GetReader() - I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

My use-case is as follows:

1. Get pdf content from an email attachment
2. Pass the pdf to a helper function, which extracts specific pages from the initial attachment
3. Pass the new PdfDocument into a function which calls Azure's Forms Recognizer API to read the fields into an object

To summarize: given a PdfDocument only, how can I get/create a byte[] from it?

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<BaseResponse> Handle(ReceiveEmailCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  var ms = new MemoryStream(command.attachments.First().Content)
  var extractedDocument = pdfService.PreparePdfDocument(ms);
  var analyzedDocument = await formsRecognizerService.AnalyzeDocument(extractedDocument);
  // Do stuff with the analyzed document...
  var response = await FileWebService.AddAnalyzedDocumentToFileSystem(analyzedDocument);
}
```

The function AnalyzeDocument expects a Stream parameter. I want to pass something like

```
new Stream(extractedDocument.GetReader().Stream)
```

Helper function implementations are below:

```
        public PdfDocument PreparePdfDocument(MemoryStream ms)
        {
            PdfDocument extractedDoc;
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms);
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
            var doc = new Document(pdf);

            var matches = GetNumberWithPages(pdf);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                var pageRange = matches
                    .Where(x => x.Number == "125")
                    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.PageIndex))
                    .ToList();
                extractedDoc = SplitPages(pdf, pageRange.First(), pageRange.Last());
            }
            else
            {
                // If we couldn't parse the PDF then just take first 4, 3 or 2 pages
                try
                {
                    extractedDoc = SplitPages(pdf, 1, 4);
                }
                catch (ITextException)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        extractedDoc = SplitPages(pdf, 1, 3);
                    }
                    catch (ITextException)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            extractedDoc = SplitPages(pdf, 1, 2);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return extractedDoc;
        }
```

```
        private static List<Match> GetNumberWithPages(PdfDocument doc)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"\s+([0-9]+)\s+(\([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\))\s+Page\s+([0-9])\s+of\s+([0-9]+)");
            var matches = new List<Match>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= doc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                var page = doc.GetPage(i);
                var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    var match = regex.Match(text);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        var match = EvaluateMatch(match, i, doc.GetNumberOfPages());
                        if (match != null)
                        {
                            matches.Add(match);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return matches;
        }
```

```
        private static Match? EvaluateMatch(Match match, int pageIndex, int totalPages)
        {
            if (match.Captures.Count == 1 && match.Groups.Count == 5)
            {
                var match = new Match
                {
                    Number = match.Groups[1].Value,
                    Version = match.Groups[2].Value,
                    PageIndex = pageIndex.ToString(),
                    TotalPages = totalPages.ToString()
                };

                return match;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

```
        public PdfDocument SplitPages(PdfDocument doc, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            var outputDocument = CreatePdfDocument();
            doc.CopyPagesTo(startIndex, endIndex, outputDocument);

            return outputDocument;
        }
```

```
        public PdfDocument CreatePdfDocument()
        {
            var baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            var writer = new PdfWriter(baos);
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            
            return pdf;
        }
```

Comment: *"I'm having difficulty understanding how to obtain the content from a PdfDocument."* - **You don't!** When you create a `PdfDocument` to write to, you initialize it with a `PdfWriter`. That `PdfWriter` in turn has been initialized to write *somewhere*. If you want to access the final PDF, you have to close the `PdfDocument` and look at that *somewhere*. Also it is not easy to retrieve that *somewhere* from the `PdfWriter` as it is wrapped in a number of layers therein. Thus, you should keep a reference to that *somewhere* close by.

Comment: Thus, usually your `ByteArrayOutputStream` usually wouldn't be created hidden in some method `CreatePdfDocument` but instead in the base method and forwarded to other methods as parameter. Then you can eventually retrieve its data. If you need to create your `ByteArrayOutputStream` hidden in some method `CreatePdfDocument`, you can return a `Pair` of `PdfDocument` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of the plain `PdfDocument`.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for helping me understand the API hierarchy better. I've re-factored my code to pass around a tuple of (ByteArrayOutputStream, PdfDocument), so in my SplitPages method I initialize a PdfDocument with a PdfWriter(baos) and copy the pages that I need and close the PdfDocument. The problem is when I return the stream I cannot access a closed stream. Should I be passing one stream that I create in my base method by reference? How do I use the stream if it closes when I close the PdfDocument?

Comment: *"when I return the stream I cannot access a closed stream"* - the `ByteArrayOutputStream` essentially is a `MemoryStream`; so you can in particular call `ToArray` even if it's closed. If you need the `ByteArrayOutputStream` as a regular stream, simply call `PdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false)`.

Comment: *"when I return the stream I cannot access a closed stream"* - the `ByteArrayOutputStream` essentially is a `MemoryStream`; so you can in particular call `ToArray` even if it's closed. If you need the `ByteArrayOutputStream` as a regular stream, simply call `PdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false)`.

Comment: @mkl You're a lifesaver! By closing the dest PdfDocument and returning the ByteArrayOutputStream by reference, I was able to call ToArray just like you said, which gave me exactly what I needed. Please post an answer so I can accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having difficulty understanding how to obtain the content from a PdfDocument.

**You don't!**

When you create a `PdfDocument` to write to, you initialize it with a `PdfWriter`. That `PdfWriter` in turn has been initialized to write *somewhere*. If you want to access the final PDF, you have to close the `PdfDocument` and look at that *somewhere*. Also it is not easy to retrieve that *somewhere* from the `PdfWriter` as it is wrapped in a number of layers therein. Thus, you should keep a reference to that *somewhere* close by.

Thus, your `ByteArrayOutputStream` usually wouldn't be created hidden in some method `CreatePdfDocument` but instead in the base method and forwarded to other methods as parameter. Then you can eventually retrieve its data. If you need to create your `ByteArrayOutputStream` hidden like that, you can return a `Pair` of `PdfDocument` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of the plain `PdfDocument`.

*By the way, the idea behind this architecture is that iText tries to write as much PDF content as possible to that *somewhere* output as early as possible and free the memory. This allows it to create large documents without requiring a similarly large amount of memory.*

> when I return the stream I cannot access a closed stream

The `ByteArrayOutputStream` essentially is a `MemoryStream`; so you can in particular call `ToArray` to retrieve the finished PDF even if it's closed.

If you need the `ByteArrayOutputStream` as a regular stream, simply call `PdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false)` for your writer to prevent the `close` of the `PdfDocument` from also closing the stream.